# react-toastr 3 with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Trying to use react-toastr in my react/TS app. But the example provided (https://tomchentw.github.io/react-toastr/) does not work.

I import like this:

```
import { ToastContainer, ToastMessageAnimated } from "react-toastr";
```

And use like this:

```
class RegistrationSelectionPage extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

 public render() {
    let container: ToastContainer | null;

    return (
      <section className="RegistrationSelectionPage">
        <ToastContainer
          ref={ref => container = ref}
          className="toast-top-right"
          toastMessageFactory={ToastMessageAnimated}
        />
        <button onClick={() => container && container.warning('No connection', 'Error!')}>Click me</button>
...
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at ./node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/classCallCheck.js.exports.default 
...
```

Which function should I call on `ToastMessageAnimated`?

Please provide a complete working example, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The @types are incorrect and look like they have allowed `any` for `toastMessageFactory` prop to get around a misunderstanding of the correct types, leading to all kinds of confusion

From the docs it expects a React factory function https://tomchentw.github.io/react-toastr/#toastmessage

The default is `React.createFactory(ToastMessageAnimated)` which is a factory function created from a Component class defined in the lib. This does serve your current purpose, but the current defs force you to specify it, and accepts `any` which defeats the point entirely idea, so lets look into fixing the defs

From the default value we can deduce the type of the `toastMessageFactory` should be `React.Factory<ToastMessageProps>` which is a factory for one of the component classes from the lib that has the basic `ToastMessageProps`

Looking up the props and the components in the source code (happily written with Flow so this becomes much easier) we can improve the `@type/react-toastr` defs as...

```
import { Component, ReactHTML, Factory, ReactNode } from 'react'

export interface ToastContainerProps {
  toastType?: IconClassNames
  id?: string
  preventDuplicates?: boolean
  toastMessageFactory?: Factory<ToastMessageProps>
  newestOnTop?: boolean
  onClick?: Function
}

export class ToastContainer extends Component<ToastContainerProps> {
    error: <P extends ToastMessageProps>(message: ReactNode, title: ReactNode, optionsOverride?: Partial<P>) => void
    info: <P extends ToastMessageProps>(message: ReactNode, title: ReactNode, optionsOverride?: Partial<P>) => void
    success: <P extends ToastMessageProps>(message: ReactNode, title: ReactNode, optionsOverride?: Partial<P>) => void
    warning: <P extends ToastMessageProps>(message: ReactNode, title: ReactNode, optionsOverride?: Partial<P>) => void
    clear: () => void
}

export interface IconClassNames {
    error: string
    info: string
    success: string
    warning: string
}

export interface ToastMessageProps {
    className?: string,
    type: string,
    iconClassNames?: IconClassNames,
    iconClassName?: string,
    closeButton?: boolean,
    onCloseClick?: Function,
    title?: any,
    titleClassName?: string,
    message?: any,
    messageClassName?: string
}

export interface ToastMessageAnimatedProps extends ToastMessageProps {
    className?: string,
    showAnimation?: string,
    hideAnimation?: string,
    timeOut?: number,
    extendedTimeOut?: number,
    tapToDismiss?: boolean,
    onRemove: Function,
    onClick?: Function,
    onCloseClick?: Function,
}

export interface ToastMessageQueryProps extends ToastMessageProps {
  style?: object,
  showMethod?: string,
  showDuration?: number,
  showEasing?: string,
  hideMethod?: string,
  hideDuration?: number,
  hideEasing?: string,
  timeOut?: number,
  extendedTimeOut?: number,
  tapToDismiss?: boolean,
  onRemove: Function,
  onClick?: Function,
  onCloseClick?: Function,
}

export class ToastMessageAnimated extends Component<ToastMessageAnimatedProps> {}
export class ToastMessageQuery extends Component<ToastMessageQueryProps> {}
```

You can now use these properly typed in your own component...

```
import { 
  ToastContainer, 
  ToastMessageAnimated,
  ToastMessageAnimatedProps // import this too for stricter typing of factory
} from "react-toastr"

//... all exactly same as your example, except...

<ToastContainer ref={ref => container = ref}
                toastMessageFactory={React.createFactory<ToastMessageAnimatedProps>(ToastMessageAnimated)}
                />
<button onClick={() => container && container.warning<ToastMessageAnimatedProps>('No connection', 'Error!', {className: 'toast-top-right'})}>Click me</button>
```

Here we are also strictly typing the options for the warning, and setting the `className` in it (this was set incorrectly as a container prop, so would not have been applied)

This also now allows you to pass JSX components as message and title too

`container.warning<ToastMessageAnimatedProps>(<div>No connection</div>, <h1>Error!</h1>, {className: 'toast-top-right'})`